# Elastic search query from SQL statement with multiple WHERE clause

Tags: elasticsearch

I need Elastic Search Query based on following SQL Statement

```
SELECT * FROM documents
WHERE (doc_name like "%test%" OR doc_type like "%test%" OR doc_desc like "%test%) AND
user_id = 1 AND doc_category = "Utilities"
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your mapping, but you can start working with something like this:

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "user_id": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "doc_category": "Utilities"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "test",
                "fields": ["doc_name", "doc_type", "doc_desc"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But I am not getting right result from it. can you please help me out how to add LIKE condition along with it. BOOL Query does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer given by [jbasko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38611/jbasko): Doing *LIKE* queries in *elsaticsearch* very much depends on your mapping of the document fields. For example if you want the equivalent of `LIKE '%test%'` in elasticsearch you need to use the ngram tokenizer for it :

```
{
 "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "some_analyzer_name": {
          "tokenizer": "some_tokenizer_name"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "some_tokenizer_name": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": <minimum number of characters>,
          "max_gram": <maximum number of characters>,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

...

and in the mapping of the fields use the analyzer:

```
"mapping":{
...
"doc_type" : {
"type" :"string",
"analyzer" : "some_analyzer_name"
},
...
"doc_type" : {
"type" :"string",
"analyzer" : "some_analyzer_name"
},
...
}
```

A short explanation about *ngram*, this tokenizer breaks the string in the fields `doc_type` and the others to small consecutive strings with the amount of characters you defined in settings.

i.e. an ngram with

```
min_gram : 1  
max_gram : 3
```

on the string "abcd".

You'll get a collection of terms: 'a','ab','abc','b','bc','bcd','c','cd','c'.  This terms will be used by elasticsearch to find the correct document using a match (or multi-match) query with inverse index.

For further reading you can search for : mapping,ngram tokenizer and termvectors in elasticsearch wiki.